# Freezing or Using Derby backup procedures For Backup

Tags: database, derby, freeze, database-backups

Taking derby backup without shutting down the database can be done in two ways :
 1. Freezing the database using SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_FREEZE_DATABASE() , making copy derby directory structure using OS commands and then unfreezing the derby database.

2. Using derby backup procedures.

   ```
       SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE()
       SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE_NOWAIT()
       SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE_AND_ENABLE_LOG_ARCHIVE_MODE()
       SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE_AND_ENABLE_LOG_ARCHIVE_MODE_NOWAIT()
   ```

As far as i know, read operations can proceed while the backup is going on.

If I have to choose one way from the two above mentioned options, which one should I go for and why ?
Is there any advantage procedures(2nd option) provide over freezing/unfreezing(1st option).